# Getting latest record in batch of records per day

Tags: sql-server

I need to query my log table to find when a price was increased.  If the price was increased more than once in one day I need to get the latest one only giving me a unique row for the item which had a price change.

Note date formats are: `MM/DD/YYYY`

**Sample Data:**

```
ProductItem      ProductPrice     ProductDateChange
=====================================================
Salmon           2.54             01/05/2005 12:20:00
Tuna             3.67             01/05/2005 09:05:00
Salmon           2.67             01/06/2005 12:25:00
Salmon           1.98             01/05/2005 15:45:00
```

These 4 records are individual price changes. You can see there are two `Salmon` rows which are on the same day but I only want the one with the latest DateTime.

**Desired Output:**

```
ProductItem      ProductPrice     ProductDateChange
=====================================================
Tuna             3.67             01/05/2005 09:05:00
Salmon           2.67             01/06/2005 12:25:00
Salmon           1.98             01/05/2005 15:45:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to return additional columns, such as the price, using a `WINDOW FUNCTION` will give you a row number for each product and change date ordered by the change date time.

When sorted `DESC` the row `WHERE LatestDailyPrice = 1` will give you the last change. Alternatively you could use `APPLY` and `TOP 1` to get the same results.

```
WITH LatestProductPrice AS
(
    SELECT
        ProductItem
        , ProductPrice
        , ProductDateChange
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductItem
                                         , CAST(ProductDateChange AS DATE)
                            ORDER BY ProductDateChange DESC) AS LatestDailyPrice

    FROM
        dbo.Product
)

SELECT
    *

FROM
    LatestProductPrice

WHERE
    LatestDailyPrice = 1
```

**UPDATED following comment:**
Or if you can't use a `Common Table Expression`, then this is exactly the same:

```
SELECT
    *

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ProductItem
            , ProductPrice
            , ProductDateChange
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductItem
                                             , CAST(ProductDateChange AS DATE)
                                ORDER BY ProductDateChange DESC) AS LatestDailyPrice

        FROM
            dbo.Product
    ) AS LatestProductPrice

WHERE
    LatestDailyPrice = 1
```

Comment: Thank you..  I get your answer and think this is the best one, however I am working in an environment where I can only select records and cannot use the With LatestProductPrice AS..  Thank you SO MUCH..

Comment: What do you mean can only select records? The above is only selecting records. `WITH LatestProducePrice AS` is a `Common Table Expression`.

Comment: @DerekJee this is an answer that actually works and gets your desired output, where as the one you marked doesn't work to get the result you require. please consider this as the correct answer and not the other one.

Comment: My query has to start with Select etc as the application is a bit limited..  But what I will investigate tomorrow is using it in my stored procedure where I can use exactly what you have offered..  How can I mark yours as the 'answer' too?

Comment: @mheptinstall i was just about to suggest that as it works the same

Comment: Hey @Tanner, thank you and I agree as you can see that this is the best answer but restrictions this minute are stopping me from using it.  The first answer will give me what I want too but will need to do a bit more code to make it..  as I asked before can I mark both as an answer?

Comment: @Tanner how does my answer not work? The original question never asked for extra columns. The answer I gave works exactly as asked for. I see no reason to downvote it.

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ProductItem), 
       MAX(ProductDateChange) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY ProductItem
```

For every individual Product item, this will give you the latest datetime value in the change table.

Comment: Thank you, I will use this in a derived table and get the other values along side that data..  Thank you too SO MUCH..

Comment: This answer is incorrect because it gives you the last `ProductDateChange` for a `ProductItem`, not by `ProductItem` and the `DATE` of the `ProductDateChange` which is a `DATETIME`.

Comment: @mheptinstall has explained why this doesn't answer the question.